# Regex.Replace with compiled option in a cycle

Tags: c#, regex

Good morning,

Let's say I have the following code, which attemps to remove any whitespace from every string in a given list:

```
foreach (String StrTmp in SomeList)
    Regex.Replace(StrTmp, @"\p{Z}", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Since the documentation of `RegexOptions.Compiled` says that "This yields faster execution but increases startup time", I would like to know if this increased startup time refers to the whole program's startup time or if it refers to the startup of every `Regex.Replace` function call inside the cycle, thus making the whole cycle slower.

By the way... Isn't there any `Regex.Remove(.,.)` command to remove every ocurrence of a given regular expression? Basically this is the same as above, but could be shorter and more elegant.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It refers to the regex compile time. But the Compiled option is designed for regexes that are created once and used often, so it makes most sense to make it once outside the loop and reuse it.

```
Regex theRegex = new Regex(@"\p{Z}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (String StrTmp in SomeList)
  string replacementString = theRegex.Replace(StrTmp, "");
```

Comment: Wrong, have a look at my comment.

Comment: What is 'wrong' ? Yes, static regexes get cached but you get a 30% runtime performance benefit with the compiled option. Exactly which is faster depends - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx - but unless your subject string is very large I think it's negligible difference.

Answer (score 3):

Reffering to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) :

> In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, all compiled regular expressions, whether they were used in instance or static method calls, were cached. Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, only regular expressions used in static method calls are cached.

IMHO you should even make it private member of your class and create it only once in object lifecycle or use static call (`Regex.<something>`) so that it is cached. In the second approach you should note that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) says this:

> When you use static method calls with a large number of regular expressions. By default, the regular expression engine caches the 15 most recently used static regular expressions. If your application uses more than 15 static regular expressions, some regular expressions must be recompiled. To prevent this recompilation, you can increase the Regex.CacheSize property to an appropriate value.

So if you optimize speed use approach with regex instance in object (or even class) and if memory is your concern use static method call.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are not cached. Every time you explicitly create new instance or call `Regex.Replace`, new instance is created. If flags include `RegexOptions.Compiled`, it is compiled every time.

Therefore the code you provided will be slow. For optimal performance, if regular expression is used multiple times, it should be created once, then reused.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\p{Z}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (String StrTmp in SomeList)
    re.Replace(StrTmp, "");
```

Comment: If you use the static methods, the compiled expressions will be cached: To eliminate the need to repeatedly compile a single regular expression, the regular expression engine caches the compiled regular expressions used in static method calls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx)

Comment: @spender Thanks for the info! Anyway, it's better not to rely on caching, especially in big applications.